# How to replace placeholder message with @Email annotation

Tags: spring

I know how to replace placeholders with actual values in Spring, and things are working for me in my application but my question is specific to below usecase.

Is it even possible to have ${malformed.email.address} replaced by actual value from properties file?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/forgot-password", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<String> forgotPassword(@RequestBody @Email(message = "${malformed.email.address}") @NotNull String emailAddress, UriComponentsBuilder ucBuilder) {

    System.out.println("Forgot password for User : " + emailAddress);

    try {
        userService.forgotPassword(emailAddress);

        return new ResponseEntity<String>("If " + emailAddress + " existed then you should receive an email soon.", HttpStatus.OK);
    } catch (ServiceException e) {
        throw new ControllerRuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

I have this configured :

```
@Bean
public MethodValidationPostProcessor methodValidationPostProcessor() {
    return new MethodValidationPostProcessor();
}
```

and I have messages.properties file in the classpath and spring's Environment object is populated.

This is my Exception Handler :

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ConstraintViolationExceptionHandler {
@ExceptionHandler(ConstraintViolationException.class)
@ResponseBody
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
public String handleValidationException(ConstraintViolationException e) {
    for (ConstraintViolation<?> s : e.getConstraintViolations()) {
        return s.getInvalidValue() + ": " + s.getMessage();
    }
    return "Invalid request supplied";
  }
}
```

This is what I get as a response :

```
WARN | 2019-02-05 00:21:16,622 | 
org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.messageinterpolation.ElTermResolver |   HV000129: EL expression '${malformed.email.address}' references an unknown 
property
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: ELResolver cannot handle a null base 
Object with identifier [malformed]
at org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:120)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:137)
at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:184)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.messageinterpolation.ElTermResolver.interpolate(ElTermResolver.java:65)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.messageinterpolation.InterpolationTerm.interpolate(InterpolationTerm.java:64)
at org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.interpolate(ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.java:75)
at org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.AbstractMessageInterpolator.interpolateExpression(AbstractMessageInterpolator.java:387)
at org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.AbstractMessageInterpolator.interpolateMessage(AbstractMessageInterpolator.java:344)
```

Comment: Remove the `$`. Message placeholders are without that.

Comment: Thanks! But it didn't work; I removed $ sign and now exception is gone but it still didn't replace the placeholder with actual value from the properties file.